# I/Choreographer(12759): Skipped 40 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm new to android programming and I recently searched for simple fade-out animation for an object. I've put it in my code, tested it and it was choppy. I checked the logs and saw this :

11-05 19:19:21.319: I/Choreographer(12759): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Here's my code in the MainActivity class

```
private MainActivity actMain;
FadeIn fadeClass = new FadeIn();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.view_switcher);
    actMain = this;

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If there are stories, add them to the table
            try {
                // code runs in a thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fadeClass.animation(actMain);
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                Log.i("---", "Exception in thread");
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

And from the FadeIn class:

```
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void animation(Activity context) {
    final View view = context.findViewById(R.id.fadeOutLayer);
    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(3000);
    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(fadeOut);

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and executing a new thread in the main thread, and inside of this new thread, you are executing a runOnUiThread, that synchronize with the Main thread and executes its content in it. It makes no sense, because is like execute the content of runOnUiThread in the onCreate.

I recommend that you use the "fadeClass.animation(actMain);" directly inside of onActivityCreated

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what do I do to run the onActivityCreated? this doesn't seem to work : 

 public void onActivityCreated() {
  fadeClass.animation(actMain);
 }

Comment: There are some things that I don't understand in your code. Why do you have a onCreate method in your FadeIn class? And why is it inflating a content view? Do you want to apply an animation in a view included in your R.layout.activity_main,right? You could put your animation method inside the MainActivity and pass the view (or the reference to the view) as a parameter. In the onCreate save the reference to the view to animate (findviewbyId),and use this reference with your method animation.About the onActivityCreated, I was wrong (it is used in Fragments)sorry. Use it in onResume or onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also animate by simply using animate() method for simple animations. Animations like alpha, rotation, scale are available. I am giving an example of translation.

```
mImageView.animate().translationX(-screenWidth)
    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).withEndAction(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
});
```

Can be done easily on main thread